# Dividing two variables returns zero

Tags: javascript

I made a simple quiz, and what I am trying to do is divide the correct answers by the total number of questions. For example, if 2 / 3, the final score in `console.log()` would be: 0.66.

```js
var correct = 0;
var totalQuestions = 3;
var finalScore = correct / totalQuestions;

var answer1 = prompt ('Question 1: what is 1 + 1?')
    if (+answer1 === 2) {correct +=1};
var answer2 = prompt ('Question 2: what is 2 + 3?')
    if (+answer2 === 5) {correct +=1};
var answer3 = prompt ('Question 3: what is 3 + 3?')
    if (+answer3 === 6) {correct +=1};

console.log(`your final score: ${finalScore}`);
```

Comment: What's `+answer1 ` ??

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you are calculating your final score before your inputs

Answer (score 4):

Your finalScore calculation in the wrong position. just placed it few lines after

```js
var correct = 0;
var totalQuestions = 3;


var answer1 = prompt ('Question 1: what is 1 + 1?')
  if (+answer1 === 2){correct +=1};
var answer2 = prompt ('Question 2: what is 2 + 3?')
  if (+answer2 === 5){correct +=1};
var answer3 = prompt ('Question 3: what is 3 + 3?')
  if (+answer3 === 6){correct +=1};

var finalScore = correct / totalQuestions;

console.log(`your final score: ${finalScore}`);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to calculate your final score *after* taking the user inputs and eveluating. It's a simple logic error.

```js
    var correct = 0;
    var totalQuestions = 3;
    
    var answer1 = prompt ('Question 1: what is 1 + 1?')
      if (+answer1 === 2){correct +=1};
    var answer2 = prompt ('Question 2: what is 2 + 3?')
      if (+answer2 === 5){correct +=1};
    var answer3 = prompt ('Question 3: what is 3 + 3?')
      if (+answer3 === 6){correct +=1};

    var finalScore = correct / totalQuestions;

    console.log(`your final score: ${finalScore}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply wrap your questions in a function and assign the `finalScore` to a variable to display the average of the correct question.

Currently you are **not** assigning **anything** to your `finalScore` when the prompt finishes it stays at `zero` because the variable not `updated` at that `stage`.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var correct = 0;
var totalQuestions = 3;
var finalScore = 0

function question() {
  var answer1 = prompt('Question 1: what is 1 + 1?')
  if (+answer1 === 2) {
    correct += 1
  };
  var answer2 = prompt('Question 2: what is 2 + 3?')
  if (+answer2 === 5) {
    correct += 1
  };
  var answer3 = prompt('Question 3: what is 3 + 3?')
  if (+answer3 === 6) {
    correct += 1
  };
  finalScore = correct / totalQuestions
  console.log(`your final score: ${finalScore}`);
}

question()
```

Answer (score 0):

These are just some lines of code. The value of `finalScore` at line 3 is simply getting logged at the last line. That's the correct.

Try creating a function to handle this quizing logic.